# Cluster merge notification in Hazelcast

Tags: java, replication, hazelcast

I host a hazelcast node in my java app, and we're running multiple instances of the app. When a node joins the cluster, or rejoins the cluster (network interruption between two nodes) there's a migration/merge process happening after the node has successfully (re)joined the cluster. Is there any way to get notifications on that process, on all nodes? So that if for instance a node that has temporarily lost network and is now back, could wait for that notification to know for sure it doesn't work on stale dat (so I'm looking for a notification for "merge is complete", and that on on all involved nodes)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the Hazelcast Cluster Events. Read more at [Hazelcast Docs, Cluster Events, Listening for Migration Events](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/events/cluster-events.html#listening-for-migration-events).

Comment: Thanks. Just one more thing - migration is one sided, iirc I'm only getting events on one side of the merge. how do I know which side will do the merge? Say I have two nodes, they lost contact at some point, which one is going to merge into the other?

Comment: Please check the merge policies: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/network-partitioning/split-brain-recovery.html#merge-policies